# How to give file as input and work in multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I have this code to find out how to get the status code from a URL:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * @author Crunchify.com
 * 
 */

 class j {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String[] hostList = { "http://example.com", "http://example2.com","http://example3.com" };

        for (int i = 0; i < hostList.length; i++) {

            String url = hostList[i];
            String status = getStatus(url);

            System.out.println(url + "\t\tStatus:" + status);
        }
    }

    public static String getStatus(String url) throws IOException {

        String result = "";
        try {
            URL siteURL = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) siteURL
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            connection.connect();

            int code = connection.getResponseCode();

                result = Integer.toString(code);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = "->Red<-";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have checked it for small input it works fine. But I have millions of domains which I need to scan. I have a file containing it.

1. I want to know how I can give file as an input to this code.
2. I want the code to work in Multiple Threads. Say Thread count should be more than 20000, so that my output will be faster.
3. How I can write the out to another file?

Kindly help me. If possible I would like to know which the Bandwidth Savvy method to do the same job. I want to make the code faster anyways. how I can do these thing with the code I have?
Java Version:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You could read the file into a List, create sublists and create threads that each work on such a sublist.

Comment: I'd say if your thread count is `20000` you'll notice that it'll be slow as a slug in glue.

Comment: @Tim Can you please show me how this is possible. I am new to Multi thread a bit in this case. Because I need to use more than 20000 threads at time. My code currently is not faster.

Comment: @Kayaman What could be the possible solution to make it faster than? I thought haviing more threads can help.

Comment: A proper solution would be something like multi-threaded and horizontally scaled. If you're not familiar with multi-threaded programming, I suggest you learn it first. Otherwise I guarantee you'll be getting into plenty of problems.

Comment: You can use an ExecutorService, set the number of active threads according to the core of the machine and use a shared object between the threads to store the results of the requests.

Comment: @davidxxx Please can you demonstrate it. I would like to see how

Comment: @Jaffer Wilson Here is a fast written solution. You should have the idea. Finally I have not used a shared object to get the result in an incremental way, I get the results at the end when all tasks were performed. I have not handle the file concerns either.

Comment: 20000 threads might be a bit overkill. I was slower than the others, but I posted an answer that fulfills your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want:

Input list file (c://lines.txt)

```
http://www.adam-bien.com/
http://stackoverflow.com/
http://www.dfgdfgdfgdfgdfgertwsgdfhdfhsru.de
http://www.google.de
```

The Thread:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class StatusThread implements Callable<String> {

    String url;

    public StatusThread(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {

        String result = "";
        try {
            URL siteURL = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) siteURL.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            connection.connect();

            int code = connection.getResponseCode();

            result = Integer.toString(code);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = "->Red<-";
        }
        return url + "|" + result;
    }
}
```

And the main program:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CallableExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Number of threads
        int numberOfThreads = 10;

        // Input file
        String sourceFileName = "c://lines.txt"; // Replace by your own
        String targetFileName = "c://output.txt"; // Replace by your own

        // Read input file into List    
        ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(sourceFileName ))) {
            stream.forEach((string) -> {
                urls.add(string);
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Create thread pool
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
        List<Future<String>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Launch threads
        for(String url : urls) {
            StatusThread statusGetter = new StatusThread(url);
            Future<String> result = executor.submit(statusGetter);
            resultList.add(result);
        }

        // Use results
        FileWriter writer;
        writer = new FileWriter(targetFileName);
        for (Future<String> future : resultList) {
            try {
                String oneResult = future.get().split("\\|")[0] + " -> " + future.get().split("\\|")[1];

                // Print the results to the console
                System.out.println(oneResult);

                // Write the result to a file
                writer.write(oneResult + System.lineSeparator());

            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        writer.close();


        // Shut down the executor service
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to:

- Create your input file and point to it (c://lines.txt)
- Change the number of threads to get the best result

Comment: Can you tell me if I want to write the output in a text file what I need to modify in your code? This is awesome and what I was looking for. Is there a way I can even make it more faster?

Comment: I updated my answer so the results are written to a file (targetFileName). For the speed, play around with the number of threads. Eventually, you will hit the performance limits (where the cost of thread creation will outweigh the speed). Also, there might be faster solutions, this is just my attempt :)

Comment: Also you can change anything in the code, it was just an example. You can remove the "// Print the results to the console" part if you don't need it, for example.

Comment: Thank you :) This was awsome solution. Still a slow as per my expectation. But will do.

Answer (score 1):

You will have issues sharing a file across threads. Much better to read the file and then spawn a thread to process each record in the file.

Creating a thread is none trivial resource wise so a thread pool would be useful so threads can be reused.

Do you want all threads to write to a single file?

I would do that using a shared list between the threads and the writer. others may have a better idea.

How to do all this depends on Java version.

Comment: I have only on file. I just want to read from it and give input to my code. But it should have ability to work on multiple threads mean I need to take 20000 or more domains at a time and process them so that my code runs faster

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ExecutorService` and set the thread number to use.
The `ExecutorService` instance will handle for your the threads management. 
You just need to provide it the tasks to execute and invoking all tasks executions
.

When all the task are performed you can get the result.
In the `call()` method of The `Callable` implementation we return a `String` with a separator to indicate the url and the response code of the request.
For example : `http://example3.com||301`,  `http://example.com||200`, etc...

I have not written the code to read a file and store in another file the result of the tasks. You should not have great difficulty to implement it.

Here is the main class :

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        String[] hostList = { "http://example.com", "http://example2.com", "http://example3.com" };

        int nbThreadToUse = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nbThreadToUse);
        Set<Callable<String>> callables = new HashSet<Callable<String>>();
        for (String host : hostList) {
            callables.add(new UrlCall(host));
        }

        List<Future<String>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables);

        for (Future<String> future : futures) {
            try {
                String result = future.get();
                String[] keyValueToken = result.split("\\|\\|");
                String url = keyValueToken[0];
                String response = keyValueToken[1];
                System.out.println("url=" + url + ", response=" + response);

            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Here is `UrlCall`,  the Callable implementation to perform a call to the url.
`UrlCall` takes in its constructor the url to test.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class UrlCall implements Callable<String> {

    private String url;

    public UrlCall(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return getStatus(url);
    }

    private String getStatus(String url) throws IOException {

        try {
            URL siteURL = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) siteURL.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            connection.connect();

            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            return url + "||" + code;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //FIXME to log of course
            return url + "||exception";
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Thread pool approach exposed here.
Multi-threading consists in exploiting the time the others threads spend to wait (I guess int his case: the distant site response). It does not multiply processing power. Then about 10 threads seem reasonable (more depending on hardware).

An important point that seem to have been neglected in answer I read is that OP talk about **millions** of domains. Then I would discourage loading whole file in memory in a list iterated over afterwards. I would rather merge all in a single loop (file reading), instead of 3 (read, ping, write).

```
stream.forEach((url) -> {
     StatusThread statusGetter = new StatusThread(url, outputWriter);
     Future<String> result = executor.submit(statusGetter);
});
```

`outputWriter` would be a type with a *synchronized* method to write into an output stream.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I will keep in mind regarding threads.